# 8 cubes ($2$x$2$x$2$) crossed by a straight line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d

There are 8 cubes forming a bigger cube whose dimension is $2$ x $2$ x $2$.
Let a straight line (or a laser) try to pierce through as many small cubes as possible.

*At most how many small cubes can be pierced through by the straight line?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A restatement of your question: Given a line in $\Bbb R^3$, at how many points may at least one of the coordinates change sign? Certainly a max is three, so the answer to your question is four, once we find such a line. If you join $(-1,-2,-3)$ to $(1,1,1)$, that line will do it.

I think a somewhat more interesting question would deal with a $3\times3\times3$ cube.

Comment: Won't the same logic show the answer is seven?  There are six planes to cross.

Comment: Probably, @Michael. The complete proof needs a verifying example.

Comment: @Lubin: If the 3×3×3 cube occupies the space $[0,3]^3$, then a verifying example would be the line through $(3,3,3)$ and $(0,\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent irrationals between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Lubin thanks for the answer, but could you do an ELI5 (Explain Like I'm Five years old)this is a question asked by my friend's kid, and i do not really understand what is $\Bbb R^3$, and what do u mean by change signs, and why the max is three time, and how that means 4 cubes are been crossed..

sorry and thanks!

Comment: Well, @JamesZen, think of the three mid planes. One horizontal, one east-west, one north-south. Now your line may cross each of these mid planes, or may not. Each time it crosses a plane, it goes from one cube to another. And you see that this is *the only way* a line can go from one cube to another. At most three passages from one cube to another, hence at most four cubes are visited.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thanks, that looks right.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you professor!